# Помогите реализовать проверку на ввод данных

Tags: c

Хочу сделать функцию чтобы она проверяла диапазон вводимых значений вместе с защитой от дурака, то есть если поле должно хранить числовое значение, то пользователь не мог ввести строковые.
Вот какая функция у меня получилась:

```
int CHECK(int a, int b, int user_number)
{

    while (scanf("%d", &user_number) != 1 || user_number >= a || user_number <= b)
    {
            printf("Ошибка ввода. Попробуйте еще раз\n-> ");
            while (getchar() != '\n');
    }
    return user_number;
}
```

а вот откуда она будет вызвана:

```
void ENTER_DATA(struct DATA* notebook)
{
    printf("Введите фамилию -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook->surname);
    printf("Введите имя -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook->name);
    printf("Введите отчество -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook->patronymic);
    printf("Введите дату рождения:\nДень -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthDate);
    CHECK(1,31, notebook->BirthDate);
    printf("Месяц -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthMonth);
    printf("Год -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthYear);
    printf("Введите адрес:\nУлица -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook->addresSTREET);
    printf("Номер дома -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook->addresHOME);
    printf("Введите номер мобильного телефона -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook->mobileNUMBER);
}
```

На данном этапе функция не работает, как задумывалась, она выводит сообщение об ошибке, даже если введенные данные корректны. Подскажите пожалуйста что необходимо исправить чтобы все заработало так как надо.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать с помощью `scanf()`, ибо он приравнивает пробелы и переносы строк - если ввести в качестве фамилии "Pupkin Vasya", например, то здесь сразу же заполнится имя. По моему скромному мнению, в данном случае лучше воcпользоваться `fgets()` или считывать посимвольно

Comment: @Андрей это я понимаю, но мне же нужно защиту реализовать, не понимаю при чем тут scanf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в проверке диапазона в `CHECK`, его следует проверять так:

```
while (scanf("%d", &user_number) != 1 || !( user_number >= a && user_number <= b ))
```

или так:

```
while (scanf("%d", &user_number) != 1 || user_number < a || user_number > b )
```

Полагаю ошибочно и то, что день рождения должен вводиться дважды, один раз в строке

```
scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthDate);
```

второй раз в `CHECK`. Непонятно также зачем передавать `user_number` в `CHECK`, его значение не используется, а `scanf` затирает его. `CHECK` просит повторить ввод пока не будет введено корректное значение, а потом возвращает его. Но вызывающий код игнорирует это значение. Цикл по getchar не нужен.  Следовало бы переписать проверку например так:

```
int CHECK(int a, int b)
{
    int user_number;
    while (scanf("%d", &user_number) != 1 || !( user_number >= a && user_number <= b ))
    {
            printf("Ошибка ввода. Попробуйте еще раз\n-> ");
    }
    return user_number;
}

printf("Введите дату рождения:\nДень -> ");
notebook->BirthDate = CHECK(1,31);
```

Comment: такой способ не рабочий, проверил. Вылетает ошибка - Debug Assertion Failed! https://i.imgur.com/QEBZsCx.png

Comment: В какой строке?

Comment: @nevalid в том месте где я хочу записать данные в файл. крч в 206 в данном случае https://ideone.com/3mC4fy

Comment: VIEW_DATA закрывает файл. Вызов VIEW_DATA(fPtr) в строке 197 приводит к тому, что все последующие действия (чтения, перемещения и запись) происходят над закрытым файлом. Поэтому запись ругается (странно что остальное не ругалось). Не надо закрывать файл (fclose(readPtr)) при вызове VIEW_DATA из APPEND_DATA и скорее всего и из других функций.

Comment: так а если я не буду буду закрывать файл то на следующем цикле изменения не будут сохраняться. К примеру я выбираю сортировку данных, функция выполняется, но если тут же вызвать функцию VIEW_DATA(fPtr) , то изменений не будет.

Comment: Если не закрывать файл, не удастся открыть его заново. Если была запись (отработала fwrite) и файл не закрыт, то чтение из него должно выдать записанные fwrite данные.

Comment: решение оказалось очень простым, так как закрывать файл внутри каждой функции было нельзя, то я fclose поместил сразу после оператора switch ,то бишь после 77 строчки, тогда и изменения в файле сохраняются и при этом компилятор не ругался. И все заработало. Спасибо за помощь)